# Invoking an internal constructor in Silverlight

Tags: c#, reflection, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance from a type that has an internal constructor, but it doesn't work,

How can I create an instance of an internal class in Silverlight?

I can get the `ConstructorInfo`, but I can't invoke it!!!

Does Silverlight support this?

Comment: What means "you can't invoke it"? Why not? What is happening? Any exceptions message you care to share...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in Silverlight we can't use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance from an internal class.

We should use `Type.InvokeMember` and use the `BindingFlags.CreateInstance`...